# Title case by using loops and not using title function python

Tags: python

How would i go about making a title case for an inputted string. I was told i have to use a loop and the title function is not allowed. The character needs to be upper case if it appears as the first character of the string, or it appears immediately following a space character, or it appears immediately following a punctuation character

```
string = input("Enter a string")
acc = ""
for char in string:
    if char in "'.,;:?! ":
        char = string.upper()
        acc +=  char

print(acc)
```

Comment: so what's the issue? why string.upper()? you just need to change the case of single character and not entire string

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Enter a string")
acc = ""
for idx,char in enumerate(string):
    if(ord(char)>=65 and ord(char)<=90):
        acc+=string[idx:]
        break
    elif(ord(char)>=97 and ord(char)<=122):
        acc+=char.upper()
        acc+=string[idx+1:]
        break
    acc+=char
print(acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each character if the next one will have to be in uppercase:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")
acc = ""
next_is_upper = True # the first character will be uppercase
for char in string:
    if next_is_upper:
        acc += char.upper()
    else:
        acc += char
    next_is_upper = char in "'.,;:?! "

print(acc)

# Enter a string: this string, will:be titled
# This String, Will:Be Titled
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code makes no reference to character adjacency.  You test the current character for punctuation ... and then try to manipulate *that* character.  Also, please don't give a variable the same name as a type (string).

Let's introduce a Boolean (flag) that tells us when we have an upcoming capitalization event.

```
str = "now is the time 12:57 p.m."  # test string
punct = "'.,;:?! "                  # punctuation set
new = ""                            # output string

cap_next = True                     # Do I capitalize the next character?

for char in str:
    if cap_next:
        char = char.upper()
    new += char

    cap_next = char in punct

print(new)
```

Output:

```
Now Is The Time 12:57 P.M.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Enter a string")
acc = ""
for n, char in enumerate(string):
    if n == 0 and char.isalpha():
        acc += char.upper()
    elif n > 0 and char.isalpha() and string[n-1] in "'.,;:?! ":
        acc += char.upper()
    else:
        acc += char
print(acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one line solution for your problem.

```
string = ' '.join(word[0].upper() + word[1:] for word in string.split())
```